# Programación Orientada a Objetos

Tags: python-3.x, poo

No termino de entender bien la POO en Python.

Es que vengo de Java, y ahí hacía un módulo con la clase y todos los métodos, y en otro módulo sólo llamaba a las funciones. Pero aqui en Python no puedo, si le pongo @staticmethod no puedo utilizar el self (que en Java utilizaba this) y si se lo quito me pide a fuerzas el argumento self.

Lo que pasa es que luego quiero usar una variable del método en sí, que se le envía en forma de argumentos en otro módulo y el argumento quiero guardarlo en una variable global de la clase y no puedo, en Java se hace muy fácil con la palabra this, pero aqui no puedo.

Comment: agrega el código necesario que llevas para de ahi partir y hacerte observaciones

Comment: Para crear un modulo con una clase y sus métodos es igual que en Java, la diferencia es que tienes que importar la clase en el otro módulo, pero como dice shadow, para darte una respuesta es más fácil con el código, revisa el __init__.py o en su caso con import

Comment: En java no puedes hacer this dentro de un método static, me imagino que en python es lo mismo y si entendi bien es lo que estas tratando de hacer.

Comment: En python, al igual que en java, para usar un método de un objeto antes tienes que _instanciar_ el objeto. Lo que en Java se hacía con `objeto = new Clase()`, en python es `objeto = Clase()`. A partir de ahi ya podrás hacer `objeto.metodo(parametros)`, y eso causará que se ejecute `Class.metodo(objeto, parametros)`, es decir, en `self` ya recibes la instancia del objeto de forma automática.

Comment: Aparte de eso, mientras que Java te obliga a programar todo dentro de clases, Python no, por lo que en realidad quizás ni necesites usar OOP. Puedes tener variables en el módulo, y funciones del módulo que accedan a esas variables. Desde el programa en que hagas `import modulo`, podrás usar las funciones poniendo `modulo.funcion()`, y acceder a las variables del módulo con `modulo.variable`. No hay OOP en este caso, ni `self`.

Comment: Te recomiendo este post de POO https://thenullpointerexceptionx.blogspot.com/2019/07/programacion-orientada-objetos.html